# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition using sql server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL server, I am trying to creating stored Procedure by using the below query:

```
Create procedure [dbo].[AddNewEmpDetails]  
    (  
          @Name varchar (50),  
          @City varchar (50),  
          @Address varchar (50)  
    )  
   as  
  begin  
  Insert into Employee values(@Name,@City,@Address)  
  End
```

How can i resolve this issue.

Comment: The insert part needs to tell SQL Server which columns of the table to put the values in, a'la `Insert into Employee (Name, City, Address) values(@Name,@City,@Address)`, otherwise the query assumes that the table only has 3 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your `Employee` table has more than three columns but you supplied here only three.

For resolution, you should mention all the columns value or mention the name of these columns in the insert statement. The second solution will work if the rest columns can accept null values. For Example

```
 Insert into Employee (Name, City, Address) values (@Name, @City, @Address)
```